# Eclipse with Java 10.0.1 not supported

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon

I was using Java 1.8 and eclipse neon. I upgraded my JRE with 1.10 from [this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre10-downloads-4417026.html).

I have changed my `JAVA_HOME` environment variable path. I have also change JRE path from eclipse.ini. I open the eclipse with an administrator. But it wasn't open. I open the log file from workspace `.metadata/.log` it shows me error as below.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-05-31 23:19:42.507
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at     java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
```

`

I have download eclipse oxygen 3a from [this link](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/).

Execution of launching eclipse has been stopped from below line.
`-jar C:\Path_TO_ECLIPSE\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0v20161219-1356.jar`
with an error `Java was started but returned exit code=13`.

Comment: You need Eclipse Oxygen.3a for Java 10

Comment: Is there any plugin for Eclipse Neon? @greg-449

Comment: If want to use Java 9 and 10 features Eclipse Oxygen.3a is required.

Comment: ok let me install it. Thanks man..! @greg-449

Comment: @greg-449. Its giving me an error like :- java was started but returned exit code = 13.

Comment: You are mixing 32 bit and 64 bit. Eclipse and Java must be either both 32 bit or both 64 bit.

Comment: @greg-449 yes it was a 32 bit eclipse set up. I have updated it and its works. Thanks, man again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172258/discussion-between-dhiral-kaniya-and-greg-449).